# Maven 3.0 packagingExcludes and order of execution

Tags: maven-3, packaging

For all of you maveneers out there, I thought I'd pass along an important order-of-execution note about packagingExcludes in maven 3 for packaging .ear files.  In your pom.xml, to assemble a .ear file, you'll have something similar to:

```
<build>
       <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
         <configuration>
          <packagingExcludes>
           db2jcc**.jar,
           db2jcc_license_cu**,
           osgi-3.6.1.jar,
...
</build>
```

It is important that the `<packagingExcludes>` tag be **the first** element after the `<configuration>` tag.  Otherwise, maven will silently ignore it.  This is for all of you who have been wondering why servlet-3.0 is still showing up in your .ear file.